Rapid Completion of Bulk Operations Webhooks Without Actual Data Import in Shopify
I am currently working with a program designed to upload JSONL files for bulk product imports. My dataset consists of approximately 56,000 products, split across around 50 JSONL files. Each file contains 1000 products and is about 10-15 MB in size, but none exceed 20 MB.
I initiate the bulk imports sequentially, relying on webhooks to confirm the completion of each import before starting the next. The process functions correctly for the first 4-5 files, with each import taking about 6-7 minutes to complete. However, after these initial files, the time reported for each subsequent webhook completion decreases dramatically – down to about 1 minute – and it appears that the products from these files are not actually being imported, despite receiving webhooks indicating completion.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues with bulk operations? How can I ensure that all products are correctly imported? Is there a way to validate that an operation was truly successful beyond the rapid webhook responses?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

If you look at the results of the webhook, they usually tell you the totalCount of the objects dealt with. If that is zero, you clearly have a problem! I am not perfectly sure of this, but it seems that is your only recourse.
